# Drupal Class not found

Tags: php, drupal, namespaces, drupal-8, psr-4

I'm trying to create a new module with a routing file pointing to a controller. But i get the following error in my logs

```
ReflectionException: Class \Drupal\glue\Controller\GlueController does not exist in ReflectionMethod-&gt;__construct() (line 128 of /home/vagrant/Projects/neut-business-website/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php).
```

glue.routing.yml:

```
hello_world:
 path: '/hello-world'
 defaults:
  _controller: '\Drupal\glue\Controller\GlueController::helloWorldPage'
 requirements:
  _permission: 'access content'
```

With following controller

project_folder/modules/glue/src/Controller/GlueController

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\glue\Controller;


class GlueController {

  public function hellowWorldPage() {
    return [
      '#markup' => t('<p>Hello world</p>')
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't really find the solution but it suddenly works after an hour of staring, changing chunks of code. I ended up with exactly the same code (did a full diff-check).I did a lot of cache clears but that didn't seem to work, i'm still curious...

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar error while creating my first drupal 8 module. I couldn't figure out the error in your case but would like to share the fault in my case.

Somehow, myController.php file was placed outside the

> /my_module/src/Controller/

folder.

Moving the file to the proper directory solved the problem.

May be this saves somebody's time someday somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

This can occur due to several reasons. In my case it was due to the mismatch in the **machine name**. Machine name of the module must match with the **namespace** which we use in the controller.

```
namespace Drupal\glue\Controller;
```

Here `glue` must be the same as the file name **glue.info.yml**

Comment: This issue was driving me crazy -- all my filenames and folder structures were correct and without mistakes, and all cases matched. Except my `.info.yml` files. Even though the folder architecture and namespace were all `Module/Controller/ModuleController`, the .info.yml was still `module.info.yml`. I didn't think the `.info.yml` files would hold such power. Thanks so much, most of the other solutions were insulting lol.

Answer (score 0):

You have a naming mismatch.

From your controller:

```
public function hellowWorldPage() {
```

From your route file:

```
 _controller: '\Drupal\glue\Controller\GlueController::helloWorldPage'
```

Note the method name vs. the path to call it in the _controller element in the routing file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I triple checked that all the files and folders were correctly named and correctly placed, and checked the namespaces.

I then renamed my Controller and inserted the new name in the namespaces, routingfile etc. and then it worked. Not sure why though.

Comment: Absolutely right, I confirm it happened with me too. Many Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, I had a similar problem, and after ensuring, all the modules folder structures and naming conventions were perfect, what eventually solved it was the lack of a semicolon after the declaration of the controller class.

For some reason my IDE was not complaining about this:

```
class FirstController extends ControllerBase {

    //code

}; // !SEMICOLON IMPORTANT
```

Comment: I strongly doubt this was your problem. You probably changed something else as well.

Comment: Class block brackets should not have a trailing semicolon.